# R: Compare a row to all the rows that come before it

Tags: r, dataframe, compare

I have a dataframe that looks something like the following. For each row within a group, I would like to compare the ID to the ID of all rows before it. In a new column, the value would be "TRUE" if the ID of the row is the same to the ID of *any* row that comes before it, and "FALSE" if it is not the same to any row before it.

```
group    id      order
1 g1    27391    1   
2 g1    29381    2   
3 g2    27391    3   
4 g2    48401    1   
5 g2    27391    2   
6 g2    27391    3   
7 g2    48401    4   
8 g3    27391    1  
8 g3    48401    2
```

So the output would look something like:

```
group    id      order  same?
1 g1    27391    1      NA
2 g1    29381    2      FALSE
3 g2    27391    3      TRUE
4 g2    48401    1      NA
5 g2    27391    2      FALSE
6 g2    27391    3      TRUE
7 g2    48401    4      TRUE
8 g3    27391    1      NA
8 g3    48401    2      FALSE
```

Comment: Do you want `library(dplyr);dat %>% group_by(group) %>% mutate(same = replace(duplicated(id), 1, NA));`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We may group by 'group', use `duplicated` on the 'id', `replace` the first element with `NA` and `ungroup`

```
library(dplyr)
dat %>%
   group_by(group) %>% 
   mutate(same = replace(duplicated(id), 1, NA)) %>%
   ungroup
```